# eCommerce apps in iPhone

Tags: iphone, e-commerce, app-store, marketplace

I have seen the in-app purchrasing programming guide for apple. But it is mandatory to pay a 30% for any e-commerce? e-commerce is different than "in-app content" -it is not an additional feature for the application-

For example, if I want to sell potatoes, this is not an app feature, it is a physical product... if I have to give a 30% of that sell to Apple... those potatoes will be VERY expensive to the consumer...

By the other way, I've seen apps that do not use apple's system, like:

unicef
zara
magento
amazon
amazon kindle

So do they have a special contract with apple or there are other ways to do so, isn't it?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 30% Apple takes only applies to:

1. Cost of your actual app, if it's not free
2. Any in-app purchases that use Apple's in-app purchase machanism

As you've noted, there are apps that facilitate the exchange of money without using Apple's in-app purchase mechanism. Apple doesn't make a claim on any such exchange, only on the two items I listed above.

Btw, the apparent Apple take is something between 30% and 40% depending on which country you're in and where the purchase was made. For example, apps sold in the UK are liable to different taxation laws/systems and you can see less than 70% of your app sale price. This isn't Apple being devious; it's just how the tax situation works out.

Comment: This pretty much sums it up. If you don't want Apple to take their cut, you've gotta roll your own authentication, purchase, ordering, etc... code.

Comment: Yup, the advantage of Apple taking their cut is that you have none of the madness of managing payment systems. Hey xus, feel free to 'tick' my answer when you're happy it's a good one :)